# SSH into Linux and Open GUI

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, remote-access

So i know how to SSH into a box and create/modify directories etc. However I do want to know how I can open the exact GUI (For instance I want the Fedora environment that I have on my virtual machine) to open up. Meaning I need to be able to simply see my linux environment. Would anyone know how I can achieve this?

I am using a mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming you want to see the gui you are running on the vm, which won't really help you here. You have a couple of options:

If you are running linux (or an X server like xceed) on the machine you are actually using, then you can enable X forwarding in ssh (-X on the command line) and then run your window manager from there.

Alternatively, you could look at installing a vnc server on your linux machine (I'd recommend tightvnc) and your host and connecting that way.

Either way this would be getting you a *fresh* desktop rather than what is visible on the console of the machine.

For the specific case of a virtual machine, as you mentioned, both vmware and virtualbox (I'm guessing you are using one of those) provide either vnc or rdesktop head support; you can then use either a vnc client or windows remote desktop client to connect to the actual console. In this instance this is probably what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a VNC server on your Linux machine, it can provide you with a desktop environment.